# How to remove white spaces between paragraph in Jsoup output paragraphs?

Tags: java, jsoup, whitespace

Here is my code. When output printing that print white space between paragraphs also. How can I remove white spaces between paragraphs and then I want to store sentence by sentence in array list.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
          String url = "http://www.divaina.com/";

          System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "cache.mrt.ac.lk");
          System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "3128");

          Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(10000).get();

          Elements paragraphs = doc.select("p");
          for(Element p : paragraphs){
            System.out.println(p.text());}
                } 
        catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
           }


}
```

When I'm directly adding content into database white spaces also adding it. How can I remove those white spaces between paragraphs? Actually I want to read content of web page and line by line adding to the database. Is there any other proper way to do it?

[image: Screen shot of out come]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously some of paragraphs contain no text. This might help:

```
for (Element p : paragraphs) 
{
    if (p.text().length() != 0)
    System.out.println(p.text());
}
```

Comment: Except some content that woks almost fine. Thanx lot dr. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression:

```
String withoutspace = whitespace.replaceAll("\\s", "");
```

Or try this

```
String withoutSpace = whitespace.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
```

Comment: White spaces comes between paragraph.One paragraph print. Then some time print spaces and then again print next paragrph. Above code not work for me.